# Should files from an RPM package be installed with root permissions?

Tags: linux, security, permissions, rpm

Our software is installed via RPM alongside a customizable service user and group. No other users need to run the software besides the service user. I've spent some time searching and can't seem to find any security best practices specifically regarding the *ownership* of said files after installation.

One interpretation of the "principle of least privilege" means that these files should be owned by the custom service user and group with the lowest mask value needed to function properly. Others have disagreed and state that the files should be owned by `root:root`.

I've run the question through Bing's AI a few different ways and it always states that it's a security vulnerability for these files to be owned by `root:root`, but then supplies reference links to completely unrelated sites.

TLDR; Is there a security best practice specific to the *ownership of files* for installed services?

Are there any potential threat vectors from `root:root` ownership?

Comment: “I've run the question through Bing's AI a few different ways and it always states that it's a security vulnerability for these files to be owned by `root:root`, but then supplies reference links to completely unrelated sites.” Screw Bing. It doesn’t know what it is talking about.

Comment: If you application requires root to install, then you'll need to use root. Are you perhaps overthinking things? The application should be installed with the least privilege necessary in order to function correctly, and it should be run as a user with the least privilege necessary in order for it to function. Perhaps I misunderstand your question. The running user will need to be able to access the files, and I don't think that means that running user has to own them, so long as you set permissions correctly.

Comment: @music2myear Well, all RPMs require root to install, I'm just wondering how the "principle of least privilege" applies to file permissions specifically and whether there's a standard. If there's the potential for vulnerabilities (as Bing AI states), then it follows that there should be some example or best practices surrounding it but I cannot locate anything of the sort. I might be overthinking it, but Bing's warnings were very ominous.

Comment: Giacomo is right: you shouldn't trust an AI for this. So stop doing that and do proper research that doesn't involve AI. I will not put my words against an AI. You have to accept that there are places AI works and places it doesn't, and this is one where it doesn't.

Comment: @music2myear Which is why I'm asking here. I've searched up and down for documentation that either proves or disproves Bing's claims and have come up with nothing. This was my last resort. If someone on SE can't provide an answer, I'm going to assume that it doesn't make a difference either way.

If you have some links for "proper research", I'd gladly review them.

Comment: One thing that IS nice about Bing's AI is that it cites it's sources. I do recommend following those links to begin with, and if you don't have anywhere better to start your research, do it there. I don't really know any better than you on this topic, which is why I am not answering. I only know that what you have read in the chat bots is not correct. Sorry, can't really be more helpful on this topic than that.

Comment: @music2myear As mentioned in the original question, the reference links are completely unrelated. One time it even provided a reference link for installing physical home security devices. None of them said anything about file permissions.